# How do I ask for a value several times?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working in a bash script but I need the script to ask for a value until that value gets empty and put the value in a variable. Lets place an example:

```
Please enter value: value1
VAR="value1"

Please enter value: value2
VAR="value1 value2"

Please enter value: value3
VAR="value1 value2 value3"

Please enter value: // script should stop asking for the same value 
                    // and continue the execution of code below this part
VAR="value1 value2 value3"
```

How I can do that in Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read -p "Please enter value: " value
do
    [ -z "$value" ] && break
    VAR="$VAR $value"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array:

```
var=()
while true; do 
  read -p "Please enter value: " val
  [[ -z $val ]] && break
  var+=("$val")
done

for elem in "${var[@]}"; do
  do_something_with "$elem"
done
```